# Use npm cache between NodeJs processes

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm writing a nodejs app, and I need to fork the main process (process.fork). I need a module to be required only once, however this module is required twice. A sample code to illustrate :

`a.js`

```
var shared = require('./shared');
var cluster = require('cluster');

if(cluster.isMaster){
    cluster.fork();
} else {
    process.exit(0);
}
```

`shared.js`

```
console.log('Hello world');
module.export = { foo : 'bar' };
```

The code in shared.js is executed twice. Is there any way to get it exectued once ? Is there a module cache per thread in nodejs ?

EDIT : In my case, `shared` contains some logging configuration using [winston](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston), and exports an API to get logging facilities. I won't post the code for confidential reasons. To get the code working, we decided to let the responsability of each thread requiring this module to configure it.

Comment: `NodeJS` is single threaded anyway, this shouldn't be hit twice.. it is something to do with `cluster.fork()`, which would suggest its spawning another instance (but I have not used cluster), which would make sense to execute a second time. `foo` would not be defined for the second instance if it was not spawned.. I don't see a problem here.. It's as designed..

Comment: `console.log('Hello world ' + process.pid);` if you try this you can see they are too seperate processes..

Comment: Right there are 2 different processes. According to @marcus-ekwall 's answer, I'll execute some code in `shared` only if this is the main thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is executed once for master and once for the fork, which is why it is executed twice.

If you only want it to execute once you could do it like this:

```
var cluster = require('cluster');

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    var shared = require('./shared');
    cluster.fork();
} else {
    process.exit(0);
}
```

You can also add the `cluster.isMaster` check within the `shared` file.

#### Additions regarding your edit

The easiest way to handle logging of your workers is to let the master process handle it. I usually do it by sending messages from the worker to the master, like this:

```
const cluster = require('cluster');

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    const worker = cluster.fork();
    const pid = worker.process.pid;
    worker.on('message', function(msg) {
        switch (msg.type) {
            case 'uncaughtException':
                // Handle uncaught exception from worker
                // Perhaps fork it again?
            break;
            case 'console':
                // Handle console logging from worker
                // Add winston code here
            break;
        }
    });
} else {
    process.on("uncaughtException", function (err) {
        process.send({ type: "uncaughtException", data: { message: err.message, stack: err.stack } });
        process.exit(1);
    });

    // Override console
    console.log = function () {
        process.send({ type: "console", method: "log", data: [].slice.call(arguments, 0) });
    };

    console.error = function () {
        process.send({ type: "console", method: "error", data: [].slice.call(arguments, 0) });
    };

    console.info = function () {
        process.send({ type: "console", method: "info", data: [].slice.call(arguments, 0) });
    };

    console.warn = function () {
        process.send({ type: "console", method: "warn", data: [].slice.call(arguments, 0) });
    };

    console.debug = function () {
        process.send({ type: "console", method: "debug", data: [].slice.call(arguments, 0) });
    };

}
```

Comment: Yes, this would only be executed for the master code, but I need to access `shared` in the child process. Thank you for this answer anyway. I'll try to use cluster.isMaster in `shared` to fix my problem.

Comment: @mguimard in that case you may find this useful also : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534462/nodejscluster-how-to-send-data-from-master-to-to-all-or-single-child-workers

Comment: @mguimard What exactly does `shared` contain? Please elaborate in your question.

Comment: Edited. But this was more a general question rather than a specific one.

Comment: @mguimard Well, there's no general answer to such a question. There are different approaches and they don't suit every situation. I'll add some comments regarding shared logging with cluster to my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I'll mark this answer as accepted (even if we chose an other strategy)